# where is the mmc write command data source from?

Tags: linux, embedded, u-boot

I am new to the boot loader world, i have a question about when we send a write command how we assign the **data source**, which is relate to the function argument ***src**? I traced the source code but i can't find where it assign the data source in c code.

Answer by myself: I found when we do **#mmc write 1 0x4 2**  the argument means **dev # 1, block # 4, count 2** which as below function's argument
  mmc->block_dev.block_write(**curr_device, blk, cnt, addr**);

**BUT,** i still want to know, is it Is it possible assign a **external** data source directly?

Is mmc write or mmc read could only write/read from internal memory?

Is it possible assign a external data source, such as from USB port or SD card?

best & regard.

```
static unsigned long mmc_bwrite(int dev_num, unsigned long start, lbaint_t blkcnt, const void *src){
int err;
struct mmc *mmc = find_mmc_device(dev_num);

if (!mmc) {
    printf("MMC Device %d not found\n", dev_num);
    return 0;
}

if (blkcnt > 1)
    return mmc_bwrite_multi(mmc, start, blkcnt, src);
else if (blkcnt == 1)
    return mmc_bwrite_single(mmc, start, src);

return 0;
```

}

How should i trace code like below?

```
mmc->block_dev.block_write = mmc_bwrite;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`src` is a pointer to a block of memory that is internal to the filesystem, if you wish to stream data from a device to the MMC, then you will need intermediate code to buffer that stream in memory and pass it to the high-level filesystem write function. You should not access `mmc_write()` directly.

> How should i trace code like below?
>
> `mmc->block_dev.block_write = mmc_bwrite;`

That is merely an assignment, not a function call.  `mmc_bwrite` is a pointer to the function:

```
mmc_bwrite(int dev_num, unsigned long start, lbaint_t blkcnt, const void *src)
```

It is a method of hooking the device driver implementation to the filesystem at run-time rather than by static link.  Within the filesystem, `mmc_bwrite()` will be called through `mmc->block_dev.block_write` rather than directly.  So

```
mmc->block_dev.block_write(curr_device, blk, cnt, addr);
```

is in fact a call to `mmc_bwrite()`.

Comment: Dear Clifford, thank you very much for your reply. As you mentioned that "if you wish to stream data from a device to the MMC, then you will need intermediate code to buffer that stream in memory and pass it to the high-level filesystem write function."   What i actually want is raw write firmware code to updating eMMC. In this case, we didn't have the file system yet. so i need to send command in mmc subsystem. As you said, i need to load the stream data into internal buffer from external device first.